# What do these operators do in D 2.0: <>= !<>= !<= !>=

Tags: d

What do these operators do in D 2.0:

- `<>=`
- `!<>=`
- `!<=`
- `!>=`

Comment: When your title contains the whole question, chances are you want to be a bit more verbose in your question ;-)

Comment: @Joachim: Haha okay. I just didn't feel like I could've added anything to the question by repeating the title, but thanks for the edit anyway. :)

Comment: you could have added to the readability. In the title font it's hard to see which characters belong together and form an operator, for example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are used for values that could be unordered, such as NaN for floats and doubles. `1 <>= NaN` evaluates to false, whereas `x <>= y` evaluates to true for any pair of numbers, as long as neither number is NaN. The other operators you mention work the same, *mutatis mutandis*.

Comment: Link to documentation: http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/expression.html#floating_point_comparisons

Comment: Thanks! :D
@stephan: Thanks for the link! I thought I'd looked everywhere (the lexical page, the operator overloading page, etc.) but apparently I'd missed it.

Answer (score 2):

The long answer:

When dealing with floating point, two values will compare as one of `A<B`, `A=B`, `A>B` or unordered (if one is NaN).

The operators represent every interesting (non constant) row in [the truth table](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/expression.html#floating_point_comparisons). They can be interpreted as testing true for each of the cases for which the operator has the corresponding char, unless it has `!` in which case the value is inverted.

Answer (score 1):

They are comparison operators in D, just like `==`, `<` and `>=`. In D the value `nan` (not a number) is taken into account. Two floating point numbers cannot only compare less, equal or greater, but also unordered, which is the case, if one of the comparands is `nan`.

Hence `<>=` means less, equal or greater. In other words `<>=` means ordered.

The comparison operators starting with an `!` return exactly the opposite of their counterpart without the `!`. In particular, all of them evaluate to `true`, if one of the comparands is `nan`.

Here's a full list of all comparison operators in D:

- `==`
- `!=`
- `>`
- `>=`
- `<`
- `<=`
- `!<>=`
- `<>`
- `<>=`
- `!<=`
- `!<`
- `!>=`
- `!>`
- `!<>`

You can find this list in [the D documentation.](http://dlang.org/expression.html) The behaviours of all of these operators is explained there.